# Maximal ideals in a group ring when the ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Is there any simple characterization of the maximal ideals in a group ring $R[G]$ when $R$ is a field, perhaps in terms of maximal subgroups of $G$?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in terms of subgroups of $G$: take the augmentation map $k[G] \to k$, whose kernel is clearly a maximal ideal but isn't really related to subgroups of $G$. Moreover subgroups of $G$ correspond to *units* so they are sort of left out of the discussion of ideals

Comment: @Max Well, I wouldn't say the augmentation ideal *isn't related* to subgroups... the augmentation ideal *is* related to $G$ itself, and the other augmentation ideals (of the form $(\{1-h\mid h\in H\})$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$) are intimately related to the other subgroups by an order-preserving lattice correspondence.  This does suggest, however, that the lattice of subgroups tells you about the lattice of ideals in the augmentation ideal. Nevertheless, I agree with your overall statement that there isn't apparently any connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximal ideals of $R[G]$ are in canonical bijection with the isomorphism classes of simple $R[G]$-modules. In one direction, if $I$ is a maximal ideal, then $R[G]/I$ is a simple ring, hence has a unique simple module up to isomorphism, which you can lift to a simple module of $R[G]$. In the other direction, given a simple $R[G]$-module $M$, take $I$ to be its annihilator.

Whether or not this characterisation helps you in any way depends on further properties of $G$ and $R$. For example if $G$ is finite, then there is a very rich theory of simple $R[G]$-modules, equivalently of irreducible representations of $G$ over $R$, namely character theory if the characteristic of $R$ does not divide $\#G$, and the theory of Brauer characters in the other, the modular case. But in the generality that you have posed the question in, I am not sure whether anything more enlightening can be said.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a promising perspective. The groups I'm looking at are (in the smallest case) limit ordinals under Hessenberg addition, making them at least countably infinite but commutative with a natural well-ordering.  Is there any literature on such group rings over characteristic $0$ fields, or perhaps more generally infinite groups carrying a total (or discrete or well-) ordering? I would also be interested in the noncommutative group case, like with ordinals under recursive addition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such characterization, and at any rate, the maximal subgroups of $G$ do not determine the maximal ideals of $R[G]$ in general.

For example, if $F$ has characteristic $0$ and $G$ is finite and has exactly one maximal subgroup (say it is $(\mathbb Z_{p^k},+)$ for example) then $F[G]$ is semisimple with at least two Wedderburn components, and hence at least two maximal ideals, potentially many more maximal right and left ideals.

Perhaps you would be happy to know what is know about when $F[G]$ is local. It is known that $F[G]$ is local if $F$ has positive characteristic $p$ and $G$ is a locally-finite $p$-group, and in the other direction if $F[G]$ is local, then $F$ has characteristic $p>0$ and $G$ is a $p$-group.

From this I think it follows that there are local group rings with many distinct maximal subgroups, providing a counterpart to the example I gave in the second paragraph.

This appears as Theorem 1 in Renault's [*On group rings*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08586.pdf) (1971). Full disclosure: I prepared the translation at this link. That's why I'm familiar with the result.

Comment: Much appreciated; the group rings I am looking at are generally not local, but I can always localize at maximal ideals to try and apply these methods.